# Calculating efficiently on large amount of data generated by wp_query

Tags: wp-query, sql, performance

I'm looking to make a series of calculations run more efficiently (my current solution takes 40 seconds for page load!).

I have a site with 40,000 posts - each of which have the following custom fields:

- Quantity
- City (there are 50)
- Type (there are 4)

I am trying to show quantity averages for each type, for each city. All 50 cities would have 4 averages. Something like this:

```
City   | Type 1 | Type 2 | Type 3 | Type 4
City 1 | 105    | 208    | 538    | 20
City 2 | 293    | 552    | 280    | 108
etc.
```

I have implemented a solution that works, but is unbearably slow (40s). What I've done is set up a series of nested wp_queries. First, I query for all city names (which also happen to exist as their own CPT), and store the current city name in a variable. While in that loop, I wp_query again for Type 1 in current city. In this second loop, I am grabbing the posts price, and using `+=` to get a total, then using `$query->found_posts` to get a post count, dividing the total by the post count. I then repeat this whole operation three more times, for the other three types.

I'm certain I'm going about this the wrong way. Any advice is appreciated. My code below:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'city',
'orderby' => 'title',
'order' => 'asc',
'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$new_q = new WP_Query($args);
while($new_q->have_posts()): $new_q->the_post();
$city = get_the_title();
?>
    <?php
    $total = 0;
    $price = 0;
    $average = 0;
    $meta_query = array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'type',
            'value'     => '1'
            ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'city',
            'value'     => $city
            )
        );          
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'         => 'items',
        'meta_query'        => $meta_query,
        'fields'            => 'ids'
        ) );
    while($query->have_posts()):
        $query->the_post();
        $quantity = get_field('quantity');
        $total += $quantity;
    endwhile;
        $new_q->reset_postdata(); 
        $count = $query->found_posts;
        $average = $total / $count;
        echo $average;
    ?>
    //repeat again 3 more times for other three categories, code removed
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: How often are these values going to change? (-> cache them)

Comment: The values themselves change hourly, it would be okay (though not ideal) to have them display as a daily update. But even with caching, wouldn't that require these queries to run at least once, meaning we still get the 40s load time once?

Comment: Well, you can run it once without user interatction ("warming the cache"), eg via a [real cron](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/wordpress/wp-cron-crontab/)

Comment: @kero Interesting. Can you verify my understanding is correct? All of this is new to me. I create a filter in functions.php that will echo all results of my 4 nested queries above. I use wp-cron to update this filter once a day. Then I use `apply_filters` to bring these results to the template file.